# LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/audit/cli

Tags: ruby, bundler

When trying to bundle exec rake -T I get a bundler/audit/cli not found error. I can bundle install, without a problem. Any ideas why this is happening? I'm on an ubuntu 14.04 system, with rvm installed.

```
$ bundle exec rake -T
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/audit/cli
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/srv/website/releases/20150309222243/lib/tasks/bundler_audit.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in `each'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:658:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:438:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/home/markgandolfo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:453:in `load_tasks'
/srv/website/releases/20150309222243/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Can you post your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a rake task that requires the [`bundler-audit`](https://github.com/rubysec/bundler-audit) gem, but that gem is either missing from your `Gemfile`, or not in the groups you are installing on this machine.

Comment: it was early and I was tired.